# How to automate issuing of AWS ACM certificates created by Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-acm

Using AWS SSL certificate provider, you can create from Terraform new certificates, but you can't use them until they're issued. The problem is that you've to create a record in Route53 to make that verification (aaaa-xxxx-vvvv. | CNAME | challenge)

Is it possible to automate that Route53 validation process after creating a new certificate with Terraform?

Here's my Terraform configuration:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "acme-cert-prod" {
  domain_name       = "www.acme.io"
  validation_method = "DNS"

  tags = {
    Environment = "prod"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Are there any options I'm missing to get that certificate automatically issued?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`aws_acm_certificate_validation` resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/acm_certificate_validation.html) will handle triggering the validation and can be linked to the creation of Route53 records with the DNS challenge.

An example is giving in the resource documentation:

```
resource "aws_acm_certificate" "cert" {
  domain_name       = "example.com"
  validation_method = "DNS"
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "zone" {
  name         = "example.com."
  private_zone = false
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "cert_validation" {
  name    = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_name}"
  type    = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_type}"
  zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.zone.zone_id}"
  records = ["${aws_acm_certificate.cert.domain_validation_options.0.resource_record_value}"]
  ttl     = 60
}

resource "aws_acm_certificate_validation" "cert" {
  certificate_arn         = "${aws_acm_certificate.cert.arn}"
  validation_record_fqdns = ["${aws_route53_record.cert_validation.fqdn}"]
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "front_end" {
  # [...]
  certificate_arn = "${aws_acm_certificate_validation.cert.certificate_arn}"
}
```